# Strict positiveness on a C*-algebra given by generators and relations.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra with generators $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ and some (non-important) relations (the relations imply that $\|a_i\|\leq 1$, so that $A$ exists). Among the given relations we have that
$$ a_1 = \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} a_i a_i^*. $$
This implies that $a_1$ is positive; I would like to prove that $a_1$ is strictly positive.

So far my attempts to prove this have been in vain. If $\phi$ is a multiplicative linear positive functional, then $\phi(a_1)=0$ implies $\phi(a_i)=0$ and then $\phi = 0$; I've no clue on the general case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you deduce from the fact that for a linear positive functonal $\phi$, $\phi(a_i a_i^*) =0$ implies $\phi(a_i)=0$?. Also, that alone doesn't seem to be enough to conclude the result.

Comment: A linear positive functional. I've edited the comment to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi$ be a state. Suppose that $\phi(a_1)=0$. Then, for some fixed $j$,
$$
0\leq\phi(a_ja_j^*)\leq\phi(a_1)=0,
$$
so $\phi(a_ja_j^*)=0$. Now, since $\phi$ is completely positive, it satisfies the Kadison-Schwarz inequality; thus
$$\tag{1}
0\leq\phi(a_j)\phi(a_j)^*\leq\phi(a_ja_j^*)=0,
$$ 
so $\phi(a_j)\phi(a_j)^*=0$, which implies $\phi(a_j)=0$. Since we have equality in $(1)$, this means that $a_j$ is in the multiplicative domain of $\phi$. As we can do this for all $j$, $\phi$ is multiplicative and so $\phi=0$.